# HTML Input field with variable ID depending on number of rows

Tags: html, pdf, printing, netsuite

I am printing a PDF using HTML in NetSuite. The PDF has a table and one of the columns in the table needs to be an input field.

The number of rows on the table will be variable each time the PDF is printed depending on the values entered in NetSuite.

```
<#if record.item?has_content>

<table align="center" border="1px" class="beta" style="margin-top:10px;width:100%;"><!-- start items --><#list record.item?sort_by("cseg1") as item><#if item_index==0>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="12" style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 229px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.item@label}</span></th>
    <th style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 276px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Description</span></th>
    <th align="center" style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 129px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Brand</span></th>
    <th align="center" style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 73px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Price</span></th>
    <th align="center" style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 84px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.quantity@label}</span></th>
    <th align="center" colspan="4" style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 118px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:12px;">UofM</span></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</#if><tr>
    <td colspan="12" style="border: 0.1px; width: 234px;"><span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>${item.custcol_ifi_small_item_name}</strong></span></td>
    <td style="border: 0.1px; width: 282px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.description}</span></td>
    <td align="center" style="border: 0.1px; width: 135px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.cseg1}</span></td>
    <td align="center" style="border: 0.1px; width: 79px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.rate}</span></td>
  <td align="center" style="border: 0.1px; width: 89px; text-align: center;"><input name="qty" id="ogqty" style="width: 40px" type="text" /></td>
    <td align="center" colspan="4" style="border: 0.1px; width: 124px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.units}</span></td>
    </tr>
 </#list><!-- end items --></table>
</#if>
```

The relevant code is the second last td tag in the table body.

The issue i am running into is that every time I inter in a value in the printed PDF, the same value gets copied in all of the row cells.

I understand that this is happening because all of the rows have the same "id" for the input field.

I have not been able to figure out what the syntax should be for the id tag for the input field so that it can be variable. Essentially each row needs to have its own id tag for the input field.

Is this possible to do within HTML?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use one of the other fields aa the ID if that field is unique? Like small_item_name? Or a counter variable?

Answer (score 0):

PDF Template uses [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/index.html) language and you can in fact use variables and value assignment, so you can define an Index variable and increment it within the loop:

```
<#assign x = 1>    
<#if record.item?has_content>
    
    <table align="center" border="1px" class="beta" style="margin-top:10px;width:100%;"><!-- start items --><#list record.item?sort_by("cseg1") as item><#if item_index==0>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="12" style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 229px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.item@label}</span></th>
        <th style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 276px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Description</span></th>
        <th align="center" style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 129px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Brand</span></th>
        <th align="center" style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 73px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">Price</span></th>
        <th align="center" style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 84px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.quantity@label}</span></th>
        <th align="center" colspan="4" style="border: 0px rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(196, 170, 197); padding: 10px 6px; width: 118px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:12px;">UofM</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </#if><tr>
        <td colspan="12" style="border: 0.1px; width: 234px;"><span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>${item.custcol_ifi_small_item_name}</strong></span></td>
        <td style="border: 0.1px; width: 282px;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.description}</span></td>
        <td align="center" style="border: 0.1px; width: 135px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.cseg1}</span></td>
        <td align="center" style="border: 0.1px; width: 79px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.rate}</span></td>
      <td align="center" style="border: 0.1px; width: 89px; text-align: center;"><input name="qty" id="ogqty_${x}" style="width: 40px" type="text" /></td>
        <td align="center" colspan="4" style="border: 0.1px; width: 124px; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:12px;">${item.units}</span></td>
        </tr>
     <#assign x++>
     </#list><!-- end items --></table>
    </#if>
```

Please note how I added the variable X value to the Input field ID